# Validation of control contained in page does not invalidate the whole page

Tags: asp.net, events, validation, forms

I have a RegularExpressionValidator for a TextBox in a control, which itself is part of another control. When I click the button to submit the form, it seems that it should not do so unless all child controls are properly validated. However, what ends up happening is that I see the validation error message pop up for each control that failed to validate before the page posts back anyway and fails when it can't parse the malformed input.

I have tried surrounding the failing code with if (Page.IsValid) {...} to make sure it doesn't run without complete validation, but the property ends up being true by the time I hit the breakpoint.

Shouldn't an entire page be invalid if any child controls are not successfully validated?

Comment: Did you work this out? I am having the same (or at least a similar) problem. The validator in a custom `.ascx` is not being called when its parent `.aspx` calls `Page.Validate()`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have different ValidationGroup controls defined?  As long as the validators in the same validation group as the button are all setup correctly, yes it should block.  Unless, for some reason, the JS is failing to load for the validators.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Set `"CausesValidation = true "` to your submit button, I guess your problem will be solved.

Comment: It is already set to true, and that's why I believe that I briefly see the ErrorMessage of the validator. For whatever reason, the form still posts back, and that's where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called Page.Validate() before using Page.IsValid ?

Comment: I did, and this doesn't change Page.IsValid to false, so something is either still not getting the proper results from the validation.